# How can I get this simple Bash command substitution to work?

Tags: string, bash, command, output, substitution

I'm trying to get a simple Bash command substitution to work but am having trouble. I'm fairly new to Bash scripting. I've read through a number of examples and the relevant section of the Bash manual, but still can't get the following bit of code to work.

What I have so far;

```
#!/bin/sh

checkString="$(/usr/bin/dscl . -read /Groups/_lpoperator GroupMembership)"

echo "$checkString"
```

This is the result;

```
localuser@tsu1:~/Desktop$ sh installcheck.sh 
No such key: GroupMembership

localuser@tsu1:~/Desktop
```

Where the empty line after `No such key: GroupMembership` is the echo of `"$checkString"`. No matter how I format it, `$checkString` always appears empty. What I'm expecting to be in `$checkString` is `No such key: GroupMembership` or whatever the result of the `dscl` command is.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect stderr to stdout

```
checkString="$(/usr/bin/dscl . -read /Groups/_lpoperator GroupMembership 2>&1)"
echo "$checkString"
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. But that gave me; 
`No such key: GroupMembership
 2>&1`
But your answer led me to the correct way to do it;

`checkString="$(/usr/bin/dscl . -read /Groups/_lpoperator GroupMembership 2>&1)"`